# Snapping to an edge of a target object along a local axis

Tags: mesh, snapping

I have set up Blender to snap to the closest edge, and in this case, selected a vertex.

[image]

I expected that when I type “G Z Z” and place my cursor anywhere along the target edge, it would snap precisely to the target edge along the Z axis. Instead, it snaps to a point in space where the X axis of the vertex points to the cursor that is placed on the target edge.

[image]

If I move the cursor along the target edge to a point where the two edges meet, it is close but not precise. Because I am modeling architecture, I prefer it to be as accurate as possible. I have read the "Similar Questions" but they don't help in this use case. TinyCad is close but it requires that the two edges are part of the same object. I also have Snap Utilities.

Up until now, I have been turning off snapping and manually getting very close by zooming in the maximum amount possible. This is tedious and I am hoping there is a better way to snap to an edge. Thanks.

Comment: If those edges were faces this could be precisely done with Knife Project (select cutter, select to be cut one, enter its Edit mode and run the tool, there's related question on that here. One of faces would be required to be elongated with Edge Slide as well). Precisely cutting edges only from different objects indeed seems to be nearly impossible by default